# Invoking remote apps with Kubuntu GUI?

Tags: remote, gui, kubuntu

Most apps run fine on the user's local system. but there are few that need to be on a remote server for performance or licencing issues.
For some user's they just use a terminal emulator:

```
ssh -X remotesys xclock
```

but for most users they will need to have the remote app look just like their local ones which they invoke via the GUI:

[image: GUI invoking local app]

How do I add these to their local Kubuntu 22.04 systems?

Answer (score 0):

Create an Application Launcher item using the command used in the terminal emulator:

**Right click** Application Launcher gear icon > **Edit Applications** > File > **New Item** > Item Name:[RemoteSys Xclock]>  Command:[ssh -X remotesys xclock] > Save